# textarea inside a div

Tags: html, textarea

I want two side by side boxes in my page for placing the comment.One will show previous comments and should be disabled.other is for current users giving comments.I have done this using two divs and placing them side by side.
one contains a textarea for placing the new comments.I am having trouble with the size of textbox and the scrollbar 
on the textarea,its appearing differently in ie6 and mozilla.Any solutions??

Comment: We're not psychics.  Post some code for us to look at and explain what the differences you're seeing are.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this problem would be having slightly alternate versions of your style sheet for IE.  IE displays scroll bars on TEXTAREAs differently than that of Firefox, which is probably throwing your DIVs out.  (The IE TEXTAREAs are slightly wider)

You could also add some extra spacing around the TEXTAREAs to prevent your DIVs from going out of alignment.

Also, do you have a container DIV?

Regards
Luke